# DropZone in ASP.NET MVC5 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, dropzone.js

I try to use dropzone.js in my project. I implemented it excactly according to this [example](http://www.venkatbaggu.com/file-upload-in-asp-net-mvc-using-dropzone-js-and-html5/). I am totaly pissed off because after drag and drop the files are uploaded however the page is refreshed and the preview images disappear. Did anyone meet this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my question deserves downwote but I hope this answer saves someone from the same struggle. After a little research I found that the problem causes new visual studio feature Browser link. For some reason after successful image uploading browser link invoked page refresh so ofcourse I lost image previews. This was unexpectable behavior.